# Extracting numbers from column then create new row

Tags: r

I have a dataset which includes multiple latitude and longitude points within the same column and also has columns with additional variables, like so:

What data currently looks like

[image: What data currently looks like]

What I would like to do is extract the numbers in multiples of 2 `(i.e. 144.81803494458699788 and -37.80978699721590175 then 144.8183146450259926 -37.80819285880839686)` into their own rows. The new rows will also duplicate the rest of the original row from which they came i.e.

What I would like the data to look like

[image: What I would like the data to look like]

I'm pretty new to R hence, perhaps, what might see like a basic question to you all. Update: I've now used

```
new$latlongs <- str_extract_all(roadchar$X.wkt_geom, "(?>-)*[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+")
```

and have the numbers/latlongs extracted including the negative sign :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Pictures are neither code nor data unless the topic is image processing. Please click on the "r" below your question, then click on "info" then read up there on how to post data and code. Having said that, you have WKT (well-known text) representations of geographic information. If you can post _real_ data_ then tons of SO R contributors have methods for how you can properly extract the data without using regular expressions.

Comment: Thank you hrbrmstr. I'll read the link and have another try at posting :)

Comment: Downvote for failure to respond substantively to the request to replace pictures with text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop that combines `gsub` and `strsplit`:

```
## The data.frame
df <- data.frame ("Polyline" = c("MultiLineString((1.1 - 1.1, 2.2 - 2.2))",
                                 "MultiLineString((3.3 - 3.3, 4.4 - 4.4, 5.5 - 5.5))"),
                  t(matrix(c(LETTERS[c(1:3,24:26)]), 3,
                    dimnames = list(c("Char1", "Char2", "Char3")))),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


#                                             Polyline Char1 Char2 Char3
# 1            MultiLineString((1.1 - 1.1, 2.2 - 2.2))     A     B     C
# 2 MultiLineString((3.3 - 3.3, 4.4 - 4.4, 5.5 - 6.6))     X     Y     Z

## Function for splitting the line
split.polyline <- function(line, df) {
    ## Removing the text and brackets
    cleaned_line <- gsub("\\)\\)", "", gsub("MultiLineString\\(\\(", "", as.character(df$Polyline[line])))
    ## Splitting the line
    split_line <- strsplit(cleaned_line, split = ", ")[[1]]
    ## Making the line into a data.frame
    df_out <- data.frame("Polyline" = split_line,
                         matrix(rep(df[line, -1], length(split_line)),
                                nrow = length(split_line), byrow = TRUE,
                                dimnames = list(c(), names(df)[-1]))
                        )
    return(df_out)
}


## You can use the function like this for the first row for example
df_out <- split.polyline(1, df)
#    Polyline Char1 Char2 Char3
# 1 1.1 - 1.1     A     B     C
# 2 2.2 - 2.2     A     B     C

## Or loop through all the rows
for(line in 2:nrow(df)){
    df_out <- rbind(df_out, split.polyline(line, df))
}
#    Polyline Char1 Char2 Char3
# 1 1.1 - 1.1     A     B     C
# 2 2.2 - 2.2     A     B     C
# 3 3.3 - 3.3     X     Y     Z
# 4 4.4 - 4.4     X     Y     Z
# 5 5.5 - 5.5     X     Y     Z
```